# Laravel: Testing muti-user logout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, phpunit

I am currently having troubles implementing tests to verify that the user indeed doesn't have the rights to perform the action whenever the previous actions has been done by the user with rights.

I have successfully implemented multi-user login using [Laravel Jwt](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) as well the controllers are being guarded properly.

**Basic setup**

There are two models (roles) the use can have:

- Staff (using staff guard)
- Member (using members guard)

**Example test flow**

1. Staff is created and logged into the system
2. Staff sends create request and record XYZ is created
3. Member is created and logged into the system
4. Member sends delete request for record XYZ and throws not authenticated error

**Expected behavior**: The record XYZ is created, then throws unauthenticated error.

**Actual behavior**: The record XYZ is created and then deleted by Member

**Code**:

```php
public function testRole_throwsNotAuthenticated() {
    // $staff & $member are created using factories

    // staff logged in & record is created
    $this->actingAs($staff, 'staff')->json('POST', '...', []);

    // member logged in & record is deleted -> should not allow this
    $this->actingAs($member, 'members')->json('DELETE', '...', []);

    // assertion removed for cleaner code 
}
```

**What I have tried**:

- Checking for the guard using before each operations

```php
   auth('staff')->check(); // returns true
   auth('members')->check(); // returns true
```

- Logout from staff before performing deletion

```php
   auth('staff')->logout(); // returns error JTW is not parsable
```

*Please note the below*:

- The same flow performed manually using REST client, the expected behavior is the result
- The login method is working absolutely as intended. The staff cannot login via member guard and vice a versa
- Separate tests to check for role and action rights are working as intended
- Due to the functionally tested hitting a 3rd party api, the record have to be created first by staff to get the necessary data for deletion